# Typescript GRPC client side interceptors

Tags: typescript, client, grpc, interceptor

I'm looking to create some GRPC interceptors on the client side of a GRPC request in typescript (not server). I know for the server we can use https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-web-interceptor, but is there a way to do this from the callers side?

The interceptors will wrap common generic usages such as for metrics with prometheus and tracing with opentracing.

There's a `grpc.Client` which looks promising (https://grpc.github.io/grpc/node/grpc.Client.html) since all GRPC clients much extend this. So has anyone been able to intercept the call to these make functions (e.g. `makeUnaryRequest`)? Would it be a simple case of extending the generated GRPC client with a custom class and overriding `makeUnaryRequest`?

I'm hoping i've missed something and there's a way to add interceptors as options such as this in Go: https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-prometheus#client-side.

Thanks!
Ankur

Comment: The grpc-web interceptor post you linked to is not about interceptors on servers, it's about interceptors for the grpc-web library, which runs on the browser, and is the client, not the server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll tale a look again and try the solution

Answer (score 2):

The `grpc.Client` documentation page you linked to shows that two of the construtor options are `interceptors` and `interceptor_providers` you should use one of those (depending on your use case) to provide interceptors to the client. The full specification for creating and using interceptors can be found in [this proposal document](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L5-node-client-interceptors.md).

Comment: Cheers, that proposal link was very useful!